# Нужно ли обособление причины в начале предложения?

Tags: пунктуация

"Из-за устойчивости чугуна к механической обработке, качество очистки радиаторов не страдает".

Нужна ли запятая перед словом "качество"? Или это цельное предложение?

Answer (score 1):

Это простое предложение: **Из-за устойчивости чугуна к механической обработке качество очистки радиаторов не страдает.**

Обстоятельство в начале этого предложения (детерминант) не обособляется и входит в основное сообщение.

Чтобы обособить оборот, надо изменить его позицию или распространить предложение, тогда оборот будет  дополнительно выделен. Такая структура позволяет **сообщить добавочную информацию  или, напротив, подчеркнуть какое-либо свойство** (в данном случае указать на причину устойчивого качества радиаторов).

Например:  Качество очистки радиаторов в этом случае, **из-за устойчивости чугуна к механической обработке,** обычно не страдает.

Вообще говоря, обособление обстоятельственных оборотов является **факультативным** и зависит от разных факторов (структура предложения,  его распространенность или распространенность предложения, позиция оборота).

То, что **оборот имеет значение именно причины, в данном случае не важно** (это же обстоятельственный оборот), этот фактор учитывается только при обособлении определений или приложений.

Answer (score 0):

Не надо запятой. Это часть предложения - обстоятельство,  а НЕ уточнение к какой-то части предложения (во втором случае его следовало бы обособить с двух сторон) С чем имеем дело, можно понять если перед уточняющей частью поставить мысленно "а именно". Подходит - уточнение, нет - обособлять не надо.

Comment: Кроме уточняющих обстоятельств, могут обособляться обычные обстоятельственные обороты, которые являются аналогами соответствующих придаточных предложений.

Answer (score 0):

В данном случае запятая не нужна.

Думаю, стилистика и семантика предложения только улучшатся, если заменить "из-за" на "благодаря". Теперь и запятую можно поставить:

**Благодаря устойчивости чугуна к механической обработке, качество очистки радиаторов не страдает.**

Comment: Ой-ё! Из-за чего-то чего-то не происходит - ничего не надо, сколь ни распространяй из-за чего.

Comment: Я так рассуждаю. Можно заменить "из-за" на "благодаря". А теперь Розенталь Вам в помощь. В частности, он приводит такой пример:  "Благодаря отличной погоде и особенно праздничному дню, улица сельца Марьинского снова оживилась" (Григ.);

Comment: Можно, но не нужно. У *благодаря* свои правила.

Comment: @GalinaAvanesova Прислушавшись к Вашим словам, я убрал это спорное утверждение (не уверен - не обгоняй :))).

Answer (score 0):

Это простое предложение: *Из-за устойчивости чугуна к механической обработке качество очистки радиаторов не страдает.*

Обстоятельство в начале этого предложения (детерминант) не обособляется и входит в основное сообщение.

Причиной обособления оборота могли бы быть изменение его позиции или распространённость предложения. Тогда обороту будет нужно дополнительное выделение.

Comment: Вторую половину ответа надо бы преобразовать в комментарий.

Comment: @AртёмЛуговой согласен, но это работа модераторов. У новичков нет привилегий для написания комментариев.