# Нужна ли запятая в этом предложении

Tags: пунктуация

**При внесении препарата, часть его микроорганизмов ускоряет процесс.**

Answer (score 1):

Запятая не нужна. Чтобы понять почему, советую прочитать ответ Арины (@Arina) на подобный вопрос (там тоже обстоятельственный оборот):
[Нужно ли обособление причины в начале предложения?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/434721/%d0%9d%d1%83%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%8b-%d0%b2-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f)